# Are MongoDB “starts with” Or "Contains" query are fast as FindByID Query?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I Want to query using part of id to get all the matched documents. So I tried “starts with” and "contains" which works find but is there any performance issue for large collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to make this search optimum :

1. Add $text index on the fields you want to do search in. This is really important because internally it tokenize your string to that you could search for a part of it.
2. Use regex which is also quicker to do.
3. If you are using aggregate, read this mongodb official doc about aggregation optimization which might help you to implement this in efficient manner : https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/
4. Last but not the least, if you are not yet fully inclined towards mongodb and project is fresh, look out for elasticsearch service which is based on Lucene. Its extremely powerful doing these kinds of searches.